# How to change new item text and href for list web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I have a list web part on a page and want to change the text, and href, from the standard new item text to something custom.

I can successfully get the (+) new item text with the following:

```
var x = $('#idHomePageNewItem').first('span').text();
alert(x);
```

However, I can't set the text using the same logic:

```
$('#idHomePageNewItem').first('span').text('hello there');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jq = $.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq('#idHomePageNewItem').text("hello there");
    jq('#idHomePageNewItem').attr("href","http://www.bing.com");
    jq('#idHomePageNewItem').attr("onclick","");
});
</script>
```

[image]